# Postgresql- Update invalid cells based on max row count

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery, max

POSTGRES-
I want update the Employees.zipcode_mod column in the Employees table for the 'invalid zipcodes' (Employees.zipcode) which are invalid if they do NOT EXIST in Ref_Zips.zip5

The update rule is to find all the invalid zipcodes that are 3 chars or long and match them on first three digits of Tmp_Agg_Zips.zip column and update Employees.zipcode_mod with Tmp_Agg_Zips.zip that has the highest number Tmp_Agg_Zips.emp_cnt. If there is a tie between multiple Tmp_Agg_Zips.zip values, then get the 'highest' zip value.

#### Update

If the invalid `zipcode` is over 3 chars but its first three digits do not match any of the first three digits of `Tmp_Agg_Zips.zip` OR invalid `zipcode` is less than 3 chars or null, then just update `Employees.zipcode_mod` with `Tmp_Agg_Zips.zip` that has the maximum value of `Tmp_Agg_Zips.emp_cnt`, irrespective of the first three digits.  Ex- 88888 and null are updated to 10012 in the example below.

This is for **Postgres 8.4**.

#### Employees

```
Gender | zipcode | zipcode_mod
   M   |  99574  |
   F   |  99574  |
   F   |  10012  |
   F   |  10012  |
   F   |  10012  |
   F   |  19001  |
   M   |    100  | 10012
   M   |    190  | 19001
   M   |     19  | 10012
   F   |   null  | 10012
   F   |  88888  | 10012
   F   |   8888  | 10012
```

#### Tmp_Agg_Zips

```
  zip | emp_cnt
99574 |  2
10012 |  3
19001 |  1
```

#### Ref_Zips

```
zip5
99574
10012
19001
```

Comment: Why does zipcode '19' get matched to zip-code '10012' shouldn't it be paired up with zipcode '19001'?

Comment: Next question - what would be the result when a you have an invalid zip such as '123' that does not match up to the first 3 of any valid zips?

Comment: @Maryam: I did *not* find a clear definition of what you want to happen. "doesn't account for .." doesn't tell us what you want to happen.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry, left that fragment while editing. The updated post defines what I want.. which is that invalid zipcodes '88888' and '8888' should be updated to '10012', using the query that you sent for 'older versions' of Postgres. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: @Maryam: I think I understand now. Added another query to my answer that should do the trick. Clarified some more and fixed typo in `emp_cnt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For updated question

I added a `COALESCE()` clause to catch the cases where no matching alternative is found. And put the computation of the default value into a subquery for multiple use.

```
UPDATE employees e
SET    zipcode_mod =
   CASE WHEN length(e.zipcode) > 2 THEN
      COALESCE((
         SELECT t.zip
         FROM   tmp_agg_zips t
         WHERE  substr(t.zipcode, 1, 3) = substr(e.zipcode, 1, 3)
         ORDER  BY t.emp_cnt DESC, t.zip  -- lowest zip for mult. emp_cnt
         LIMIT  1
         ), t0.zip)
   ELSE
      t0.zip
   END
FROM  (
   SELECT zip
   FROM   tmp_agg_zips
   ORDER  BY emp_cnt DESC, t.zip
   LIMIT  1
   ) t0
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   ref_zips r
   WHERE  r.zip5 = e.zipcode
   )
```

#### For original question

This query works with **older versions** of PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE employees e
SET    zipcode_mod =
    CASE WHEN length(e.zipcode) > 2 THEN (
        SELECT t.zip
        FROM   tmp_agg_zips t
        WHERE  substr(t.zipcode, 1, 3) = substr(e.zipcode, 1, 3)
        ORDER  BY t.emp_cnt DESC, t.zip -- lowest zip for mult. emp_cnt
        LIMIT  1
        )
    ELSE (
        SELECT zip
        FROM   tmp_agg_zips
        ORDER  BY emp_cnt DESC, t.zip
        LIMIT  1
        )
    END
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   ref_zips r
        WHERE  r.zip5 = e.zipcode
        )
```

In **PostgreSQL 9.1**, a [CTE](http://7.8.2.%20Data-Modifying%20Statements%20in%20WITH) should perform better:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT zip
    FROM   tmp_agg_zips
    ORDER  BY emp_cnt DESC, t.zip
    LIMIT  1
    )
UPDATE employees e
SET    zipcode_mod =
    CASE WHEN length(e.zipcode) > 2 THEN (
        SELECT t.zip
        FROM   tmp_agg_zips t
        WHERE  left(t.zipcode, 3) = left(e.zipcode, 3)
        ORDER  BY t.emp_cnt DESC, t.zip  -- pick lowest zip
        LIMIT  1
        )
    ELSE
        x.zip
    END
FROM   x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   ref_zips r
        WHERE  r.zip5 = e.zipcode
        )
```

If there are multiple rows in `tmp_agg_zips` with the same (highest) `emp_cnt`, I pick the "lowest" `zip`. You did not specify how to break these ties.

BTW, different column names for zip codes are not helpful for me. Table-qualifying the column names does a better job.

Comment: Thank you very much. The logic for lowest zipcode works. And sorry about the confusing column names.

Comment: @Maryam: no need to be sorry, I was just giving my opinion. :) Cool that it works.

Comment: Brandstetter :As @JCooper pointed out "what would be the result when a you have an invalid zip such as '123'that does not match up to the first 3 of any valid zips?"I didn't see that earlier and that test case failed. So I was trying to add that condition-WHEN length(e.zipcode)>2 and e.zipcode not exists (select 1 from tmp_agg_zips t where t.zip=e.zipcode) THEN (SELECT zip FROM  census.zip_pop1 ORDER  BY pop DESC, zip LIMIT  1) But'not exists' is not working with the case statement. I tried not in as well, but that's not working too.Treat it the same way as it treats null. Any idea? Thx

Comment: @Maryam: You need to **define** what you want to happen in clear words first. Don't put that in a comment, edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: Brandstetter: Edited the question. Please check the 'updated' statement for the missing logic. Thanks again.